# Convert a Date to a useable format to insert into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

All,
I have the following date:

Wed Feb 01 2012 09:30:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

I'm trying to insert this into my mySQL database. The field I want to insert this into has a structure of DATETIME. Is there a simple way to insert this or do I have to do something to insert in correctly into the DATETIME correctly?

I don't think my hosting company has the highest version of PHP to use DateTime as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Wed Feb 01 2012 09:30:00 GMT-0600'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$date='Wed Feb 01 2012 09:30:00 GMT-0600';
$targetDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date));
```

date()  function is bundled with all versions of php . You can convert date from any format .